# Programmatically create Site Collection in Sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio-2008, collections, sharepoint-2007

I am new in SharePoint. Can anyone tell me how to create Site Collection pro grammatically in Visual Studio in SharePoint 2007. Please it's request that tell me from the basic steps. Like What i have to take in Visual Studio.. where to write code ... Under which method i have write what code....???

Kindly Reply Me..!!

Thanks In Advance ...
Kishan

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information on this easily available via your favourite search engine:

Try [Creating a Site Collection Programmatically](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Creating+a+Site+Collection+programmatically+using+the+object+model)

and [SPSiteCollection.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsitecollection.add%28v=office.12%29.aspx)